# Centering multiple images in CSS side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner at CSS and HTML so I'm sure this is a mess. But what I'm trying to do is center 3 images side by side in a horizontal center in CSS. I've tried different solutions have gotten them to align properly but they still stay stuck to the left of the page or will stack on top of each other (and sometimes overlap).

```
<div id="imagesMain">
    <img src="IMG_20140930_140020.jpg">
    <img src="IMG_20140922_164619.jpg">
    <img src="IMG_20140608_181811.jpg">
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#imagesMain{
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}
#imagesMain img{
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

The images by default are huge. the 2nd CSS block resizes them but I can't get them to do much else. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean to say, images are of different widths and heights and you want them vertically and horizontally centered?

Comment: Side note, `vertical-align: center;` isn't valid.

Comment: @j08691 That's not side note man, that's the main point. `:)`

Comment: Check my update ! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the almost same CSS, but with one simple correction, **change**:

```css
vertical-align: middle;
```

And **remove** these:

```css
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
```

There's no `center` here. It must be `middle`. Please correct it. And remove `display: inline-block` from the `<div>`. Your final code should be like:

```css
#imagesMain {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#imagesMain img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesMain">
  <img src="IMG_20140930_140020.jpg">
  <img src="IMG_20140922_164619.jpg">
  <img src="IMG_20140608_181811.jpg">
</div>
```

Click on <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> and press <kbd>Full Page</kbd> to check if this is what you are expecting.

Comment: the images will not center due to     vertical-align: middle;   It will center just due to text align center try removing  vertical-align: middle; it will not affect any thing

Comment: @Shree29 Why do you say?

Comment: Both of these worked. Thank you. I figured it was something easy but I was missing it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bL7h0xk5/ without vertical-align: center; still images are centered

Comment: @Shree29 `vertical-align: middle`! Duh!!! And in your fiddle, there's no `vertical-align` at all!

Comment: but images are centered which is needed by @someoneelse6

Comment: Now what's the problem with my answer?

Comment: So we just need one property text-align: center; and not other required, right ?

Comment: @Shree29 Yes! Because the images are of same height, it is not required. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `display: inline-block` to `display: block` (as well as removing `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`. If you're ok with `#imagesMain` taking up 100% of the width of the screen, with the images centered inside, this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try learing flexbox because it has many uses for nicely aligning items and content.
it also keeps your css very small.

if you would like to keep them centered al the time. you should use `justify-content: center;`

```css
#imagesMain{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#imagesMain img{
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesMain">
    <img src="IMG_20140930_140020.jpg">
    <img src="IMG_20140922_164619.jpg">
    <img src="IMG_20140608_181811.jpg">
</div>
```

for alternative uses look at [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) they give good examples for how to use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is the container, because the image are correct align to the center, I have simplify your code and colored the container and images:

```
#imagesMain{

    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;

    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    margin-top:20px;

    background-color:red;

    text-align:center;
}
#imagesMain img{
    background-color:blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left:-4px; /* trick for remove the space beetwen */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bcpph0pp/1/

**UPDATE**

Reading other comments I think you want all aligned in the middle, this is a good resource for generate the code for FLEX BOX: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

And this is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/bcpph0pp/2/